# SDL reports only 24bpp display modes even though the monitor supports 32bpp

Tags: windows, directx, sdl

I'm trying to switch my application from DirectX to SDL video backend and just finished writing the code that returns all the supported display modes for the current display device.

However unlike DirectX that returned color depths of 32bit, 16bit and even 8bit for the display, SDL returns 24bit and 16bit instead.

I'm using `SDL_GetNumVideoDisplays()` and `SDL_GetNumDisplayModes()` to loop over all available modes and check every mode for details with `SDL_GetDisplayMode()` and `SDL_BITSPERPIXEL()`.

Whats the reason for this behavior, as far as I know my monitor should support a 32bit color depth (its also configured like that in my desktop/nvidia settings) so why does SDL only report 24bit instead and misses 8bit completely? (not that I would care for the latter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same thing. The monitor only actually supports 24 bit colors (8 bits of each color channel). But a lot of color formats use 32 bits per pixel, and just leave 8 bits unused.

Comment: If its the same thing, why calling it 32bit in the first place if the monitor only supports up to 24bits? Shouldn't there be a differentiation between color format depth and color depth of the monitor?

Comment: Well, I don't know where you're seeing 32bit, so I can't really answer why it says 32bit there. :)

Comment: For example http://i.imgur.com/AlUDNY8.png or http://i.imgur.com/zQHIxCm.png (check Color depth and Monitor BPP)